# Tkinter filedialog askopenfilename settings

Tags: python, tkinter

I am trying to use a tkinter filedialog.askopenfilename() method to be able to select image files for a generator. I am setting it up within a class as that is what I found was the 'correct' method of doing so. As far as I know, this should be the correct format for calling this, though it just kind of a bodge of the few explanations I could find.

```
class Application(tk.Frame):
    def __init__(self, master=None):
        super().__init__(master)
        self.master = master
        self.pack()
        self.pickedfiletypes = (('png files', '*.png'), ('jpeg files', '*.jpeg'))
        self.create_widgets()

    def create_widgets(self):
        ...

        self.fileselect = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(self,
                                    initialdir= os.getcwd(),
                                    title= "Please select a file:",
                                    filetypes= self.pickedfiletypes)
        ...

root = tk.Tk()
app = Application(master=root)
app.mainloop()
```

```
TypeError: askopenfilename() takes 0 positional arguments but 1 was given
```

All the tutorials and examples I see give it positional arguments.
This is an example I found on pythonspot.com, which looks pretty much the same from what I can tell aside from not using a variable.

```
root.filename =  filedialog.askopenfilename(initialdir = "/",title = "Select file",filetypes = (("jpeg files","*.jpg"),("all files","*.*")))
```

Answer (score 1):

remove self in

```
self.fileselect = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(self,
                                    initialdir= os.getcwd(),
                                    title= "Please select a file:",
                                    filetypes= self.pickedfiletypes)
```

it works!

Comment: Ok, so that worked, but why? Isn't the first argument for the parent window? Also, that means it opens a window to select something, but I wouldn't be able to change the selection, or choose when to open it. Since it should have multiple images to be selected, that'll be really frustrating.

Answer (score 1):

self isn't used because parent isn't required this is because of askopenfile,askopenfilename, or askdirectory creates window. 
For reference use (https://pythonspot.com/tk-file-dialogs/)

```
self.fileselect = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(
                                    initialdir= os.getcwd(),
                                    title= "Please select a file:",
                                    filetypes= self.pickedfiletypes)
```

When using tkFileDialog parent needs to be used it doesn't have a popup window.

```
tkFileDialog.Open(parent=self, filetypes=filetypes)
```

Answer (score 0):

if you want to specify the parent of the file dialog window, then you have to specify it. you can do so by doing parent = self.

```py
self.fileselect = tk.filedialog.askopenfilename(parent = self,
                                                initialdir = os.getcwd(),
                                                title = "Please select a file",
                                                filetypes = (('png files', '*.png',
                                                            ('jpeg files', '*.jpeg'),))
```